# Is the developer survey broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey

I've been trying to complete the new developer survey but it keeps jumping back to the very beginning and I have to click through all the questions I've already completed to get back to where I was. It's getting too tedious to have to keep doing this so I have regretfully been forced to abandon it for now. (For what it's worth, I don't normally have any problems with surveymonkey.)

Answer (score 10):

**Update**: should be fixed now.

---

Yes, and SO is aware and looking into it.

(I ran into this too, and had it confirmed that there is an issue in a private chat room).

Comment: Many thanks - that was quick - I gave it one last go and managed to get all the way through this time!

Answer (score 10):

There were some minor bugs with the survey, that while being fixed sent you back to the start page. They should be resolved now.

Comment: I possibly missed some of the questions due to this bug. For example, I never saw [the question referenced in this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341410/who-the-heck-is-caroline), unless you're showing different questions to different users.

Comment: Also, there was no way to go back or review answers before submitting, just a "next" or "done" button.