# Who the heck is Caroline?

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2017

This survey question describes a certain Alice, then asks me what I'd recommend to... Caroline?

[image: A question from the 2017 Stack Overflow Developer Survey that reads, "Let’s pretend you have a distant cousin named Alice. She is 24 years old, has a college degree in a field not related to computer programming, and has been working a non-coding job for the last two years. She wants your advice on how to switch to a career as a software developer. Which of the following options would you most strongly recommend to Caroline?" to which my choice of response is, "Who the heck is Caroline?" The names Alice and Caroline are accentuated with gratuitous freehand circles.]

Comment: TIL BoltClock only has one friend in life, cannot comprehend having two :-P "Does not compute..."

Comment: Who the heck is Caroline? It is being talked about Alice.

Comment: That alternate text, though. Props.

Comment: I bet Bob will know.

Comment: Or possibly Neil Diamond.

Comment: Then again, she might be living next door to Alice.

Comment: They both worked for Cave Johnson, I believe...

Comment: -1 for discriminating against people with two first names.

Comment: The funny thing for me is that I *have* a relative who at 24 decided to change careers from a completely unrelated one into coding. I answered based on what they did.

Comment: @BradLarson That song is in my head, and blame has been assigned to you.

Comment: I don't know, go ask Alice.

Comment: The funny thing for me is that I have a relative who at 24 decided to change her name from Alice to Caroline. Also, I don't think I saw that question on the survey.

Comment: I had this question on the survey, but by the time I saw it, Alice had transitioned to Robert.

Comment: This is probably a test to see if you're paying attention

Comment: Darn it, I was just going to ask this question.

Comment: I didn't run into this question. Judging by the bug where the survey finishes at 40-50%, I'm guessing we're not being shown all questions. This doesn't look like a 'further information' question. Any reason people aren't given the same surveys?

Comment: They don't call the service Survey **Monkey** for no reason. Someone isn't getting a banana tonight...

Comment: Her name is Caroline Alice ;)

Comment: [Who the f*** is Alice?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw08Py5nz1w)

Comment: Is it intentional that some of these answers seem hilariously bad? Would anybody seriously recommend to a person with no prior experience in programming that they should start by participating in a hack-a-thon, an open source project, or a programming competition? Even "apply for a remote working position and hide your complete lack of programming knowledge by asking bad questions on SO so other people do your work for you" seems like a far better and more realistic option...

Comment: @Boltclock i was going to ask the same question but instead of alice i want to ask how i know Globex's hiring process??

Comment: Did SO doing marketing about globex :p

Comment: I like how you can choose "None of these" and three others.

Comment: @l4mpi TBF, it doesn't say she has no programming experience - just no professional programming experience in the last 2 years, and an unrelated degree. If she's like a lot of people who want a development career, she may well have hobbyist programming experience.

Comment: Maybe she's só distant that the person writing the question just forgot the name halfway through.

Comment: I didn't see this question. Are there multiple versions of the survey?

Comment: @l4mpi besides what Jo already said, a couple of other possible reasons: to test the person's knowledge of tech terms; to motivate/scare Carolice by spending an excruciating long sleepless time in front of a computer trying to be productive when her entire frustrated team blames her lack of knowledge.

Comment: @l4mpi Caroline could have programmed as a hobby for 20 years. Why would she want to work as a programmer, if she has no skills?

Comment: It's obviously GLaDOS.

Comment: Lack of skill should never decrease desire to participate. I lack the skills to sing but it doesnt stop me jumping on the mic and belting out my favourite songs at the top of my tone deaf lungs :D

Comment: I believe carolin is Klaus's crush..

Comment: Answer: `None of these`, since you're not talking to Caroline... (or `Something else` > `400`) ;)

Comment: It's typically Alice, Bob, Caroline and Mallory. So the question expects you to know who typically is who.

Comment: Why isn't there an option "endlessly ask inane beginner questions on Stack Overflow and treat the site as an interactive tutorial"?

Comment: Hah, did you make the question choose a gender for the example people at random? I don't remember these names. That's pretty awesome PC pandering especially given that a single respondent in isolation wouldn't even know that's what you did!

Comment: @Lundin: Because, given the feminine names and pronouns, such a demeaning option would stir up a riot /s

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: You mean you received the same question with a different set of names?

Comment: @BoltClock: I could have sworn yes! They were male names. _But_ I have been known to hallucinate, and it was several hours ago, and I wasn't paying that much attention to the preamble at the time. So I could be misremembering.

Comment: Getting the same thing, but with Robert and Bob: [pic](https://imgur.com/bB6ICSl)

Comment: Yeah, there you go.

Comment: @Dartmouth: I didn't know Caroline was the short form of Alice. (For those who don't get it: Bob is the short form of Robert, so it doesn't seem wrong in that context.)

Comment: On weekends, Robert calls himself Alice. But don't tell Caroline about it.

Comment: @BoltClock neither did I. But it's still confusing with Bob and Robert too. Any chance of this getting fixed?

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen "Why would they want to work as a programmer, if they have no skills?" - that's what I constantly ask myself about many people already employed in this industry...

Comment: @BoltClock I don't get that, how can a longer name (Caroline) be a short form of a shorter name (Alice)? Is there a [Carolice](http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/carolice) or Caralice involved?

Comment: @CPHPython: yes, Bolt was being sarcastic. *I didn't know that ..* is a common retort, stated in an incredulous tone (obviously lost in a text-only medium).

Comment: Caroline does have all the letters from Alice. What are 3 more letters to you? :)

Comment: @l4mpi Clearly someone experienced in unemployment

Comment: @l4mpi Some live hackathons *do* provide "beginner" support (much to my consternation, the annual local one here is nearly exclusively people who have clearly never seen an IDE before). So *that* one isn't necessarily as crazy as it sounds.

Comment: @Machavity: You're actually replying to l4mpi - StringForever was being a gigantic weirdo copying and pasting random parts of other people's comments and answers on meta. I fixed your comment.

Comment: @BradleyDOTNET: See above.

Comment: Something else: "Google". Really, though. --- Time, dedication, and the internet gives you everything. Grab tutorials. **Make up a project goal.** Get to it, and you'll learn the problem-solving skills schools struggle to teach, because you'll have to. Look up best practices when you have a grasp. That's how I learned.

Comment: Caroline is actually giving you a real test. Sounds more like this. [Homework vs Classwork](http://imgur.com/gallery/jiy9ktZ)

Comment: Caroline nor Alice.

Comment: On a serious note, a thought: for this question in particular, it would have been interesting to have two versions, one with a male and one with a female person (and maybe a third with a name that could refer to either gender, or an explicitly gender-neutral version). Serve the versions randomly. If there are significant differences and/or bias patterns/correlations, analyse. If not, rejoice. (For extra fun, add dismissive answers like "Too late, go be a teacher" or something like that.)

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212583/i-wonder-what-a-company-cage-looks-like. ;)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This one's my bad, folks.  It's a typo, supposed to be the same name.  We're going to correct it in a non-disruptive manner over the weekend.

Comment: "in a non-disruptive manner" ... you're going to kill Caroline, aren't you?

Comment: @Bart Caroline? Who the heck is Caroline???

Comment: Alice/Caroline → non-disruptive →  **Coralice**

Comment: You're one of the authors of the survey? Considering all the complaining about it, you all should had been much, much more active at SO.

Comment: @Bart You should think of it as a long term reassignment of her biochemical potential.  An assignment assistant would be happy to assist your understanding should this still trouble you :) ...... Happiness flows from the wisdom of Friend Computer.

Comment: The participate on meta privilege is awarded at 5 reputation, and you neither have that nor a moderator badge.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ He is an employee; doesn't need either.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET How's that stored at that database level?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ It’s in SEDE & the API (`is_employee: true`). [SOX](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/34727) shows a Stack Overflow icon next to employee’s usernames.

Comment: @Teemu Implying folks on meta has anything else to do than complain? It does seem you've been around a while but you seem quite new here ;)

Comment: @Cœur I think it should be Caralice, because it's Caroline, not [Coraline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coraline)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Me new here? My current Meta stats says "_visited 785 days, 28 consecutive_". I haven't been highly active though. A big part being "complaining" at Meta, yes, but there's a lot of other objectives too, discussion about new features and moderator elections, guiding etc. The amount of the meta posts about the survey felt exceptional to me. [survey-2016] was tagged to 21 posts, this year survey has already 17 posts, and that doesn't include discussion about the results, which are still ahead. And the comment above was meant to be a pure joke, ofcourse.

Comment: @Teemu: I assume the "You must be new here" is an attempt to play along with your joke - but I could be wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, now you've said it, that is very possible. I couldn't find a connection with the first reading with my limited skills of English, though.

Comment: @Teemu yes indeed, I was trying to be funny here, with arguably bad result. Sorry if you felt attacked on that!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No worries, I didn't feel attacked at all. This "language barrier" is the main reason, why I haven't been more active at Meta. I simply don't understand all the finesses of the language. After all, the english used on the main page is usually much simpler than here.

Comment: I seriously thought this was a trick question, thus my answer was 'none'.