# The survey isn't accepting my email address: Validation blocks the `+`

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2017

The developer survey isn't accepting my [perfectly valid](http://www.hitechyo.ga/2013/07/countless-aliases-of-your-gmail-address.html) email address:

> [image]

I suspect the `+` throws it off. The censored part is just some letters.

My profile accepts that same address just fine.

---

Also, note that the validation message says it's a "comment", which isn't accurate.

Comment: Same problem here. Also, I heard that some TLDs are rejected, e.g. `.solutions`

Comment: Uh oh. Someone is using a regex to validate an email address.

Comment: @CodyGray: Probably copy-pasted from SO >.>

Comment: Wonder if this is a SurveyMonkey issue...

Comment: I hate it when websites do that.. It's like restricting passwords to a max length of 12 chars..

Comment: [*cough cough*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35945002/476)

Comment: *"just some letters"* – because it cannot possibly be "cerbrus@gmail.com"… ;)

Comment: @deceze: it could be, but it's not :P (Can you guys see our addresses?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ugh.  I'm really sorry about that.  Using the "+" trick is a wise precaution, and the software should support it!

We don't have direct control over the regex used to validate, other than being able to turn it off entirely.  We'll be doing that along with a few other bug fixes over the weekend.

In the meantime, allow me to reiterate that we're not selling, distributing, or otherwise using the emails collected from volunteers for any reasons other than the types of follow-up studies specifically mentioned on the form.  So if you did end up giving us your "non-plussed" email, it will be kept safe.

Comment: Yea, I figured I'd just dump the plus part :P

Comment: I'm not worried about the security; it was for my convenience categorizing incoming email.