# Most Ridiculous Hacker Personality Survey Results

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

So the [survey results](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=hero-ind-ques#community) are in!

But I didn't see results on the most ridiculous hacker personality question :(

Seeing those results (and getting a badge) were the best parts of the survey to me :J Can I get someone to give me a data dump on those results?

Comment: [Caroline has them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341410/who-the-heck-is-caroline)

Comment: Last year they released the raw data, but not until July. I suppose we'll find out then. https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/12/you-can-now-download-stack-overflows-2016-developer-survey-data/?cb=1

Comment: Team [Hackerman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEkrWRHCDQU)!

Comment: @JonasWielicki The ridiculosity index determination of a given hacker is often difficult to determine. For example hackerman, has a near perfect ratio of technical terms to technobabble, but he's obviously cast into a tongue-in-cheek role. Which means he's ineligible for the multiplier granted for a role that takes itself seriously. In that aspect I think it's hard to beat [Patton Plame](http://ncis-new-orleans.wikia.com/wiki/Patton_Plame).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit 3/28/2017:  The [blog post is now live](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/28/realistic-developer-fiction/)!

A blog post based on these particular results will be coming out next week.  For a sneak preview, listen to [this week's podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/22/podcast-105-wait-developer-survey-2017-results/?cb=1).