# Take the 2018 Developer Survey today - Unexpected Error

Tags: bug, survey-2018

I am getting this error while filling the survey form.

[image: Screenshot of an error dialog on top of the 2018 Developer Survey. The survey is displaying the salary question page.]

```
Sorry, an unexpected error occurred.
#B.xxx88r.jca12z1d
```

Operating System: Windows 10 (not activated)
Browser: Google Chrome

Comment: could you just also edit in what you was doing when this error appeared, like did this appear as you loaded the page or when you clicked on something

Comment: this appears when clicking next or prev with filled or non-filled values. I tried twice by taking a fresh survey.

Comment: just spitballing (I think that is the word?). do you have any extensions interfering? did you try disabling them?

Comment: there are not extensions interfering..or I don't see any pop-ups also

Comment: That was unexpected....

Comment: Clearly the user is expected to fix `#B.xxx88r.jca12z1d`. That's a trivial thing to do.

Comment: [Please circle the error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/203553) - I'm having trouble seeing it...

Comment: Perhaps that error means you have too many tabs open in Chrome?

Comment: I blame [Caroline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341410/who-the-heck-is-caroline)

Comment: @DavidG I had 261 other tabs open in Firefox, (about 220 were cached) when I took the survey, so that can't be it!

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It was just a joke, but you clearly need to seek medical assistance. Stat.

Comment: @DavidG I understood it was a joke :). I'm feeling fine though.

Comment: Finally completed the Survey !!!.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks All, Finally completed the survey. Probably they may have fix the issue.

[image]