# Why haven't I received a gift card for testing this year's questionnaire?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

I received an email, asking to test this year's questionnaire.

It was said that I would receive gift card as a thank you. I provided my email in the end, but I got nothing. It's not like I can't live without 5$ gift card, but still...

Comment: You should ask [Caroline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341410/who-the-heck-is-caroline)

Comment: @KenWhite I can't believe my ears. A lot of hostility. As stated in my question, gift card is not really meaning of my life. I asked this question simply because nowhere in the email was stated the waiting time and I have no idea about the process of receiving / ordering one. That's why I asked, no hard feelings, no "urge for instant gratification". I would test survey anyway, no reward needed.

Comment: There was no hostility intended. I'm sorry it appeared that way. It just always surprises me when people think that the entire globe is now *free two-day shipping* or *download now*. It happens here frequently for other things, too. *Thirty seconds ago, I did something that should have earned me this badge, but it hasn't shown up yet. Why not?*. People forget that the servers here have better things to do than real-time monitoring of badges, and that it's much better to process them at scheduled times when there are fewer things happening..

Comment: Still haven't received it :(

Answer (score 45, accepted):

We are waiting a week for all of the survey test results to come in, so we can download all of the email addresses at once and start the fulfillment process. One of our employees will then have to manually submit the email addresses to the various gift-card companies we are using. (We have to use different providers for different countries, each one with a different process.)

You will definitely receive your gift card, it's just going to take a little while to receive it. We appreciate your patience, and more importantly, we appreciate that you took the time to test this year's survey.

**Update - 24 Jan 2019**

We have been able to send gift cards out to some of the test participants, but not all. We have run into unexpected difficulties for some countries, based on region-specific logistical challenges (local laws, shipping issues, lack of coverage by our providers, etc.). We are still working through these issues, and will update affected users directly when we know more. Thanks for your patience!

**Update - 12 Feb 2019**

After researching multiple gift-card providers, we discovered that there are some countries we simply can't send gift cards to. For the roughly 800 users in this category, we are reaching out to them directly today and offering to send their reward via PayPal. If these users consent to share their contact info with PayPal, we will process their reward within the next week.

Unfortunately, there was a small subset of users (about 100) in geographies that Amazon, PayPal and other gift-card providers do not do business in. We are reaching out directly to these users today, letting them know that we are unable to provide the promised USD$5 incentive. We are deeply sorry (and more than a bit embarrassed) that we weren't able to keep our word.

**Update 19 March 2019**
As of today, everyone who was owed a gift card has either been taken care of or notified that we can't fulfill their request.

It took us much longer than we anticipated, because we had to fulfill PayPal manually, and we quickly discovered that there were many countries PayPal would not let us pay, including India and Israel.

After much searching (and wailing and gnashing of teeth), we discovered a provider called Rybbon that has a worldwide gift card that covers many geographies that Amazon and PayPal don't cover. We were able to send gift cards to nearly 230 remaining users.

We still found that there were some countries we couldn't fulfill: neither Amazon nor PayPal nor Rybbon carries out financial transactions there. All of the affected users were notified via email -- about 20 additional users, on top of the 100 we had already notified in February.

We thank everyone for their patience -- this took a lot longer and turned out to be much more complicated than we envisioned. We've learned from this situation and will make sure it never happens again.

Comment: So, 6 to 8 weeks? ;)

Comment: I never seem to get invitations for these things any more :( Feels a bit cruel to pay people for things that other people weren't even given the option to do. Ah well.

Comment: Blimey, I just realised how people must feel when they're discriminated against in job openings!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe you opted out of those in your [email settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynK1U.png) (I have added red freehand circles, arrows and underlines to help you find the options, you're welcome ...)  ;)

Comment: @rene Aagggghhh! I discriminated against myself! (thanks :P)

Comment: Why must it be region specific? I don't even have amazon in my country

Comment: Any new on this? Havent heard back yet...

Comment: @dhein We reached out to everyone via email, either with the actual reward or with a note explaining that we were unable to pay in your region. Please go to the contact us form and explain that you never received your gift card, and ask that your request be routed to Anita Taylor. Please make sure to include any email addresses you might have used to sign up. I will research on the back end and get back to you personally. https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: @Anita Taylor I wiĺl do so tomorrow. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 5):

I just (2019-01-17) got it, so it was only 6-8 days.

It was an Amazon gift card localized in Italian. I'm Swedish but since I live in Italy, I guess that's fine.

[image: Amazon Gift Card]

Thanks SE!

Answer (score 1):

I just received(18-03-2019) mine as 10$ virtual master card.
[image]