# I didn't see some questions during the survey

Tags: support, survey

After completing the survey, I discovered through meta posts and chat that I had missed at least two questions. I did not skip these questions, I never saw them at all.

- Alice/Caroline wants to switch careers.
- Something involving a "Documentation on Stack Overflow" choice.

While answering the survey, I encountered the [navigation bug described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341401/is-the-developer-survey-broken) where <kbd>Next</kbd> would occasionally go back to the first page. I just clicked through until I got back to the question I was answering. Additionally, I had the [problem with the percent complete being off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341414/survey-ends-at-57-intentional-joke-or-actual-bug).

I linked my profile during the survey, if that can help find and diagnose the issue.

I understand that [some questions are context sensitive or randomized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339532/would-you-like-to-test-the-2017-developer-survey), but given the other navigation issues I want to confirm that it was intentional and not a bug.

Comment: Can't remember those two questions either, but I think some questions are conditional and only shown based on what you answered in a previous question. For example, I answered that I taught myself a programming language and after that got asked about how I did it, or I answered that I'm a student and got a question related to that later.

Comment: I considered that some questions might deliberately not appear, but given the other bugs I wanted to be sure. Neither of these seemed particularly context-sensitive.

Comment: From [Would you like to test the 2017 Developer Survey?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339532/would-you-like-to-test-the-2017-developer-survey): _"This year some questions are only asked of a subset of survey takers based on previous responses or randomly assigned groups."_ So... Potentially the case? I have no idea how the Alice/Caroline question (which I also didn't see) could be context based at all, same as you.

Comment: I got questions about Robert and another male name, but not Alice/Caroline. Maybe there's an algorithm that's assigning each survey taker a gender and presenting Robert or Alice or Pat based on that? These questions appeared before the actual "how do you identify" demographic question.

Comment: Those issues (next button / percent bar) seems more a SurveyMonkey bug than SO's fault. Regarding the missing questions, you may have answered something that triggered a different sub-set of questions.

Comment: Perhaps, depending on one's background, it wouldn't be relevant to give advice to Bob/Alice/Caroline/Robert. Suppose you don't have much work experience, then how would it be relevant for you give career advice to Bob-Alice?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not quite sure how Stack Overflow structured the survey, but in Survey Monkey you can use questions using Skipping Logic, therefore skipping some questions or even triggering different kinds of questions.

Here is Survey Monkey Docs on [Question Skip Logic](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Question-Skip-Logic)

Regards to finish at 57% or at 44%, it really seems like a Survey Monkey bug, and as stated in other [Question's comment by a mod](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341414/survey-ends-at-57-intentional-joke-or-actual-bug#comment431667_341414), the progress bar will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that you can set up skip questions in surveys, and I know that the percent thing was a bug, but this doesn't really answer my question, it just restates information.

Comment: Well I confirmed the bug from progress bar.

Comment: OK, but that wasn't my question. I linked the percentage issue in my question, it had already been confirmed.

Comment: @davidism I see what you're getting at, but the way your question is worded, dippas's answer appears to answer it. I think the question you are trying to ask is more along the lines of "Assuming the following questions are conditional, what are the trigger conditions for them?" or something like that. If the answer is "No, those aren't conditional.", then you have a bug. Otherwise, you can check your answers with the triggers.

Comment: @tehDorf The answer I'm looking for is an employee to say "you didn't miss anything due to the navigation bugs" or "you did miss something".

Comment: @davidism Unless those questions are not conditional, I don't think you are going to get an answer because your question is too narrow - it only applies to you. I wouldn't imagine an employee taking the time to go look up your individual questionnaire and review it for errors. It seems likely those questions were conditional, and a lot of people are probably curious about the conditional questions, so you'll probably get more interest (and an answer) if you rephrase your question.

Comment: @tehDorf thanks, but I'm explicitly not interested in the conditional questions except as they pertain to "there was no error, that was normal conditional question behavior". Given that the other navigation errors affected everyone during the first hour, I don't think it just applies to me, even if it doesn't apply to everyone.